# Why isn't this a valid sleeping location in Terraria?

Tags: terraria

My house is right next to the dungeon and is also underground by a couple of blocks. There are 6 blocks in between the floor and ceiling, and in between the two walls are 10 blocks. There also are 2 torches, a work bench, and a chair.

For some reason it's not a valid sleeping area though.  Help?

[image: my house]

Comment: Dirt back walls don't count for housing; so that's a cave, not a house.

Comment: Would you sleep in such location?

Comment: @Braiam I would in Minecraft! Or in 20,000 BC.

Comment: Dirt walls only work if you place them